First login always fails
I have a few machines that I have strange issues when trying to login to them. When I use RDP to login using Servername.domain.com with domain\labuser I enter the password and it fails but when I re-enter the domain\labuser and password combination it works but only if I re-enter the domain\user combination again.
In checking the RDP logs I can see my successful attempts but I don't see any kind of failure, I do however see it receiving the RDP attempt
Didn't find anything in the logs and added the domains to the search domains in TCP/IP settings.
